# How to access Google Places API Next Page Token in React Native using Axios?

Tags: axios, react-native, google-places-api, react-native-ios

I've been learning react native and I was developing a simple app showing some restaurants in a location based on the keyword given using the Google Places API in axios. I was able to get the next_page_token but I don't know how to use that pagetoken to run my fetching again. Please help.

*My SearchScreen.js*

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar';
import useResults from '../hooks/useResults';

const SearchScreen = () => {
  const [term, setTerm] = useState('');
  const [searchApi, results, errorMessage, pageToken] = useResults();

  return (
    <View>
      <SearchBar
        term={term}
        onTermChange={setTerm}
        onTermSubmit={() => searchApi(term)}
      />
      {errorMessage ? <Text>{errorMessage}</Text> : null}
      <Text>We have found {results.length} results</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles=StyleSheet.create({});

export default SearchScreen;
```

*useResults.js*

```
import { useEffect , useState } from 'react';
import GooglePlaces from '../api/GooglePlaces';


export default () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [pageToken, setPageToken] = useState('');

  const searchApi = async (searchTerm) => {

    try {
      const response = await GooglePlaces.get('/json', {
        params: {
          location: '-33.8670522,151.1957362',
          radius: 1500,
          type: 'restaurant',
          keyword: searchTerm,
          key: 'MY_KEY_GOES_HERE',
          pagetoken: pageToken
        }
      });
      if (response.data.status == "OK") {
        setResults(response.data.results);
        setPageToken(response.data.next_page_token);
        console.log(results);
        if(pageToken!='') {
          console.log("Next Page");
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setErrorMessage('Something went wrong');
    }
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Hi There");
    searchApi('pasta');
  }, []);

  return [searchApi, results, errorMessage, pageToken];
};
```

I am able to return the pageToken function. Since Google Places API returns 60 results, I need to use that pageToken to run the api two more times so that I could get maximum results. Now, I gets only a maximum of 20 results.

Comment: Your `useEffect` is running just at the beginning. You have to find what would be the changing state that triggers a new call in order to get the new data coming from GooglePlaces.

Comment: @RafaelMora it runs just at the beginning once. actually there is a callback from that textInput for that searchApi function.

Comment: Try `onTermSubmit={(e) => searchApi(term,e)}` and on put in that function as first line of code `e.preventDefault()`. Make sure your params function also change `searchApi(term,e)`

Comment: @RafaelMora can u please explain in detail ? I am just a beginner.

Comment: `const searchApi = async (searchTerm,e) => { e.preventDefault() ....` the rest of the function

Comment: you should add `<SearchBar />` component code to your question.

Comment: @RafaelMora  what is the type of e ?

Comment: `e` is the click event, an object.

Comment: @Levi Can you provide your GooglePlaces.js or your baseURL?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you need to concatenate the `token` and `key` into the base URL as query string parameters:

```
'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?pagetoken=' + token + '&key=' + key
```

Comment: @AntonMenshov: That's not a link to the solution. It's a string concatenation including a URL which purports to solve the issue.

Comment: Manu: FYI: I've edited your answer to help clarify that this is a string concatenation of a URL, and not a link to an answer.